# How does generator really work?(Python3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm new in python. I recently learned about generator and filter(I assume it's also a generator). Then I got really confused about the following code:

```
>>> def _not_divisible(n):
        return lambda x: x % n > 0

>>> def _odd_iter():
        n = 1
        while True:
                n = n + 2
                yield n

>>> def primes():
        yield 2
        it = _odd_iter()
        while True:
                n = next(it)
                yield n
                it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it)

>>> for n in primes():
        if n < 1000:
                print(n)
        else:
                break
```

In my understanding, there are actually three generators(including filter) in the code. **'_odd_iter'** is all the odd numbers. **'primes'** are all the prime numbers. And **'filter'** is the prime numbers except 2.

But in the primes(), **'next'** is the first element of **'it'**, and then it passes to the **'_not_divisible'**, so I think in the equation **'it = filter(...)'** the left **'it'** is a number equals to **'n'**. How could the **'it'** as a number again pass to **'next()'**.

```
>>> next(primes())
2
```

One more question, no matter how many times I use 'next', it always returns 2 instead of the prime stream.

**Thank you very much for helping me**

Comment: It always returns two because `primes()` is always a new generator. Do `p=primes()`, and then call `next(p)` several times.

Comment: What are you actually asking before you get to the second question?

Comment: `filter` doesn't return a single number. It takes a function and an iterable as args, and returns a new iterable that yields the values that are True-ish, according to the function arg.

Comment: What does filter really return when the _not_divisible is passed with 'n', a number instead of a list.(Sorry about the indistinction, English is not my mother language.)

Comment: Note that `_not_divisible` is a function _factory_. When you pass it `n`, it returns a function that takes a single arg (`x`); that function returns True when `x` isn't divisible by the `n` you originally passed to `_not_divisible`.

Comment: Is it possible just use the _odd_iter and _not_divisible in filter without using a generator again in the primes  to implment the function.

Comment: Sure. You can replace those `yield` statements in `primes` with print calls. Then `primes` will be a plain function that prints the primes, instead of being a generator that yields them. Of course, you'd also need a way to break the infinite loop. Or just hit Ctrl-C. :)

Comment: And why I must use p=primes() and next(p) instead of next(primes()) to make it?

Comment: Don't worry too much that this functional programming stuff is a bit confusing. That's quite normal. :) And this is a moderately complicated example. FWIW, this _isn't_ a very efficient way to calculate primes (although there are lots of ways that are worse). This code isn't trying to be an efficient prime calculator: it's a demo of functional programming techniques.

Comment: As L3viathan said in the very first comment, each time you do `primes()` you create a fresh new iterable that starts at the very beginning of the prime sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

`primes()` returns a generator. When yielding from *it* (not from `primes()`), the following happens:

1. It yields `2`, once.
2. `it` gets set to the generator that `odd_iter()` returns, which yields all odd numbers starting with `3`.
3. An infinite loop is entered.
4. We get the next element from `it` (the first time this is `3`) and yield it.
5. Now comes the tricky part: `it` gets assigned a filter object that takes the previous `it` and only lets numbers through that aren't divisible by the last yielded number.
6. Go to 4.

What this means is that this generator is nested one more layer each time we get a prime. Perhaps this is best illustrated by looking what `it` is:

1. `all odd numbers starting with 3`
2. `all numbers not divisible by 3 in (all odd numbers starting with 5)`
3. `all numbers not divisible by 5 in (all numbers not divisible by 3 in (all odd numbers starting with 7))`
4. `all numbers not divisible by 7 in (all numbers not divisible by 5 in (all numbers not divisible by 3 in (all odd numbers starting with 9)))`
5. ...

---

As I said in my comment, the reason `next(primes())` always returns 2 is that each call to `primes()` returns a new generator. What you mean to do is:

```
>>> p = primes()
>>> next(p)
2
>>> next(p)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are an unbounded number of generators in this code.

`it` is always a generator.  Every time through the loop, a prime number is emitted, and `it` is replaced by a filtered version of itself that eliminates multiples of that number.  Example: at the moment the number 11 is emitted, `it` is:

- a filter eliminating multiples of 7, on top of
- - a filter eliminating multiples of 5, on top of
- - - a filter eliminating multiples of 3, on top of
- - - - the original generator of odd numbers.

...for a total of 5 active generators, including `primes()` itself.